# Django | Page not found (404) No Cars matches the given query

Tags: python, django

I tried to create a form for creating a new article on the site, but this error came out.
I've rechecked everything 10 times, but I don't understand what the error is.

hello/urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='hello'),
    path("cars/<slug:car_slug>/", views.car_slug, name='car_slug'),
    path('cars/addpost/', views.addpost, name='addpost')
```

]

hello/views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *

def index(request):
    data = {}
    return render(request, 'hello/index.html', data)



def car_slug(request, car_slug):
    car = get_object_or_404(Cars, slug=car_slug)
    data = {
        'car': car
    }
    return render(request, 'hello/car_pk.html', data)

def addpost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Cars.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
            return redirect("hello")
        else:
            form.add_error(None, "Ошибка добавления поста")

    else:
        form = AddPostForm()


    data = {
        'form': form,
        'title': 'Добавление поста'
    }

    return render(request, 'hello/addpost.html', data)
```

hello/forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from .models import *

class AddPostForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label='Название', max_length=300)
    slug = forms.SlugField(label='URL', max_length=40)
    content = forms.CharField(label='Характеристика', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':60, 
'rows': 10}))
    is_published = forms.BooleanField(label='Состояние', required=False, initial=True)
    brand = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Brands.objects.all(), label="Бренды", 
empty_label='Не выбрано')
```

hello/models.py :

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db import models



class Cars(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Название")
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name="URL", unique=True, db_index=True, max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Характеристика", null=True)
    time_create = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата публикации', auto_now_add=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True )
    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brands', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('car_slug', kwargs={'car_slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Машины'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Машины'


class Brands(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Бренды", max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name="URL", unique=True, db_index=True, max_length=255)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Бренды"
        verbose_name_plural = 'Бренды'
```

Here is a photo from the error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYhAT.png)
ацукацуп ццкдлпцкдпоьйзщцозщайусз айцоащойцжаойждалойжвдлаожфывдлао жфывдлаофывджл аофыдлаофывждалофывж длаофывжд лаофывжадло ывфжалдофвыжадл фоывжадл фыовжадлф

Answer (score 1):

Does it show up in the Shell? `python manage.py shell`

```py
from hello.models import Cars
Cars.objects.filter(slug='insert_car_slug').first()

# if above is empty run this:
for i in Cars.objects.all():
    print('slug:', i.slug)
```

I think the issue might be that *slug* Url field.. cause it validations as a full Url. When going to that View you are only passing it `addpost` which wouldn't be a full Url ..maybe just change that field to a CharField

---

and in the **addpost** View, inside the `form.is_valid()`, it can be like:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect("hello")
```

Might be better to do it that way so the Forms are in the Forms & Views are in the Views.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and check

```
def car_slug(request, car_slug):
    car = Cars.object.filter(slug=car_slug)
    data = {
        'car': car
    }
    return render(request, 'hello/car_pk.html', data)
```

show us the error from your terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try to test again with ASCII characters slug.

It looks like you are generating some Unicode characters which will not work with django slug https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters.

According to their docs

> slug - Matches any slug string consisting of ASCII letters or numbers, plus the hyphen and underscore characters. For example, building-your-1st-django-site.

So in order to work with Unicode slug, change your router path to:

```
path(r'cars/(?P<slug>[^/.]+)/', views.car_slug, name='car_slug'),
```

Update the regex part [^/.]+ if you need something else to validate the path.